# How to map cassandra date type in spark encoder?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to implement simple aggregation on cassandra table. but can't map cassandra date type in spark. Tried to map `String`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`, `java.time.LocalDate`, `org.joda.time.LocalDate`. None of those working. Can you tell me what java type is correct for cassandra date type?

```
// table definition
CREATE TABLE data (
    day date,
    value bigint,
    // ommited
);

// result model
@Data
class Item {
    String day;
    Long count;
}

// spark query
sparkSession
    .read()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .option("keyspace", "keyspace")
        .option("table", "data")
        .load()
    .groupBy("day")
        .agg(functions.sum("value").as("sum"))
        .as(Encoders.bean(Item.class))
        .collectAsList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.sql.Date working except day shifting problem.